# Python & setuptools - 'No module named...'

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to package an app I've written in Python, and am using setuptools with find_packages to do so. If I run `python setup.py develop` (or `install`) I get an ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python34\Scripts\jiragen-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('jiragen==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'jiragen')()
  File "x:\jira\jiragen\jiragen\main.py", line 8, in main
    import jira_parser, worklogs, exporter
ImportError: No module named 'jira_parser'
```

jira_parser.py, worklogs.py and exporter.py all exist in the same directory as main.py. Here's my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
        name='jiragen',
        version='1.0',
        packages = find_packages(),
        py_modules = [
            'jiragen.main', 
            'jiragen.jira_parser'
            ],
        install_requires=[
            'PyYAML',
            'XlsxWriter',
            'jsonpickle',
            'requests'
            ],
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [
                'jiragen = jiragen.main:main'
                ]
            }
        )
```

Note that I explicity added items to py_modules to see if that would make any difference - but python still complains it can't find jira_parser. Exactly the same error with just `find_packages` and no `py_modules`. I've tried adding the packages in explicitly too.

My directory structure looks like:

```
jiragen
|--setup.py
|--jiragen/
|--|--__init__.py
|--|--__main__.py
|--|--main.py
|--|--jira_parser.py
|--|--worklogs.py
|--|--exporter.py
|--|--excel/
|--|--|--__init__.py
|--|--|--(other .py files..)
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Solved - Needed to change the target in `'console_scripts'` from `jiragen.main:main` to just `jiragen:main`, and add the line `package_dir = {'': 'jiragen'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have module `jiragen.py` named as parent package. This can be an issue if you use absolute imports.